# PHP - Passing a class's variable to another class

Tags: php, json, oop

I have a class that returns a `$values` variable (defined in the `Request()` class), and I have this on the php file that calls both:

```
$requestImport = new Request();
$requestImport->request();
$import = new Import($dbh, $values);
$import->import();
```

It gives me this error: `Undefined variable: values`. Here is where I get the `$values` variable from (ignored the lines above and below because it's a bit long):

```
$importData = json_decode($contentResult);
foreach ($importData as $value) {
    $filter = [];
    $filter['CategoryName'] = $value->CategoryName;
    $filter['CategoryId'] = $value->CategoryId;
    $values[] = $filter;
}
return json_encode($values);
```

If it helps, here's my constructor in the `Import` class:

```
public function __construct($dbh, $values) {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}
```

I'm using `$values` in a foreach loop like this:

```
public function import() {
    foreach ($values as $insertData) {
        $this->values['categoryName'] = $categoryName;
        $this->values['categoryId'] = $categoryId;

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO t_virtuemart_categories_en_gb (
        category_name, id)
        VALUES
        (:categoryName, :categoryId)
        ;");
        $stmt->bindParam(":categoryName", $categoryName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":categoryId", $categoryId);

        $stmt->execute();

    }
}
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do it (`$values` is a json string to insert stuff into the db) any advice on to improve it would be helpful, too. If you need any additional information, I'll add it.

Comment: Where do you define `$values` before you pass it? You can't give something that doesn't exist to a person so why should you be able to do that in code?

Comment: @Script47 In the Request class. I'll explain it now!

Comment: You did not define `$values`. You are trying to use the variable in the `import()` function, but it's not defined. You are also sending it to the construstor as a parameter, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: @Newwt As mentioned, although that value is used in the `import` function, it is never passed to it (via the constructor). Please learn about PHP OOP.

Comment: Do you understand variable scope? You can't use a variable unless it's been declared previously, if it's inside a function you'll need to return it to use it or change its scope...

Comment: @Script47 That's what I'm trying! I'm getting the error on the `foreach` when trying to use `$values` and on `new Import($dbh, $values);`

Comment: @mattfryercom I'm returning the $values variable from Request and trying to use it on Import. I thought that was how it worked :/

Comment: @Newwt in your constructor you're passing in `$values` but not using it - there are a few problems so it's hard to see exactly what one is causing the issue you're concerned about.

Comment: I recommend reading about variable scope and brushing up on OOP, good luck : )

Comment: @mattfryercom That's what I'm doing, and trying to practice, but it doesn't help that when I try to put stuff to practice, the answers I get are basically "lrn2program". I appreciate all suggestions and explanations, so thanks for that, I guess.

Comment: @Newwt If you refine your questions so that they are more specific it will be easier to help you, everybody wants to help but we can see that the main problem is that your understanding is flawed. Solving your problem without encouraging you to learn the cause doesn't help you. Once you experience a problem like this you should break it down into smaller sections and test each part, so that you can identify what section isn't working the way you expected it to, then if you're still unable to figure it out post that refined example. I hope that helps : )

Comment: @Newwt This might help, when you return $values from your function (I'm assuming this is within a function as there's no way for me to see that from your code), you need to store the returned value before you can use it outside the function. So you might call your function and store the return value in a variable that you can then use, like this: `$myVariable = myFunction();`. Does that help?

Comment: @mattfryercom You mean I should be doing for example `$values = new Request(); $values = $values->request();` for the `$values` variable inside the Request class?

Comment: @Newwt No, I'll explain: `$values = new Request();` creates a new `Request` object from the `Request` class (the blueprint for the object). Then `$values->request();` calls the `request` method (function) of that object.... I don't think you're going to get anywhere with this unless you're much more specific with your question and I would suggest that your understanding of OOP is flawed and you need to brush up in order to understand how to solve your problem, if you post another question tag me and I'll try to help but there are too many mistakes in this one and it's too generalised. Thanks

Comment: @mattfryercom I will. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define `$values` from the file you are calling the class.

In your loop, `$values` is being defined inside. This means it is out of scope anywhere else in your code.

```
$importData = json_decode($contentResult);
foreach ($importData as $value) {
    $filter = [];
    $filter['CategoryName'] = $value->CategoryName;
    $filter['CategoryId'] = $value->CategoryId;
    $values[] = $filter;
}
return json_encode($values);
```

You need to fix this by defining `$values` outside of the loop.

```
$values = array();
$importData = json_decode($contentResult);
foreach ($importData as $value) {
    $filter = [];
    $filter['CategoryName'] = $value->CategoryName;
    $filter['CategoryId'] = $value->CategoryId;
    $values[] = $filter;
}
return json_encode($values);
```

You also need to make it a class level variable by using `$this` in the constructor.

```
public function __construct($dbh, $values) {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
    $this->values = $values;
}
```

And then access it from the `import()` function.

```
public function import() {
    foreach ($this->values as $insertData) {
        $this->values['categoryName'] = $categoryName;
        $this->values['categoryId'] = $categoryId;

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO t_virtuemart_categories_en_gb (
        category_name, id)
        VALUES
        (:categoryName, :categoryId)
        ;");
        $stmt->bindParam(":categoryName", $categoryName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":categoryId", $categoryId);

        $stmt->execute();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lars Petersons answer:

the variable $values must be defined in the php file that calls both classes:

```
$requestImport = new Request();
$values = $requestImport->request();
$import = new Import($dbh, $values);
$import->import();
```

watch out, your import function has many errors like the declaration of $categoryName and -id.

```
public function import() {
    foreach($this->values as $insertData){
        $categoryName = $insertData['categoryName'];
        $categoryId = $insertData['categoryId'];
        ...
```

**edit**: after i understood better what op wanted to achieve i changed my answer a bit

Comment: Coincidentally, `$values = $requestImport->request();` is exactly what I changed, it's fantastic to see I wasn't going the wrong way for once, thanks!  Something I don't understand is why I now get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. Is it because `$this->values` is not an object or array?

Comment: look at the changes of the Import-constructor that Lars made in his answer. you need to add the line `$this->values = $values;`

Comment: oh, wait. actually its because $this->values is jsondecoded at that moment. in the import-constructor decode it. `$this->values = json_decode($values, true);`. Why was it jsonencoded anyway?

Comment: just a silly mistake from another thing I tried, and accidentaly left it there. Just fixed it!

Comment: Yes. Now I'm figuring how to insert all the data via PDO. For some reason it only inserts the first result in the json string, but I think I can fix it myself.